# В чем разница между cmdlet'ом и функцией?

Tags: powershell

В [манифесте модуля](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest) есть два элемента: cmdlet и function.

В чем разница между cmdlet'ом и функцией?

Comment: Cmdlet - класс, наследуемый некоторому базовому классу .NET, например, PSCmdlet, логика которого хранится в двоичном файле (сборке). Function - один из провайдеров PowerShell, хранящий пары "имя - скрипт-блок": скрипт-блок описывает логику вызываемых командлетов, а также методов и свойств типов .NET, имя указывает на конкретный скрипт-блок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получил ответ на [англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911385): cmdlet - это .NET class, написанный на C# или на другом языке .NET и содержащийся в .dll. Функция - это скрипт, написанный на языке PowerShell. скрипт может быть отдельным файлом, входить в модуль или быть непосредственно указан в командной строке.

Также добавили, что функции бывают простыми и advanced functions. advanced functions - это функции, у которых проставлен атрибут [[CmdletBinding()]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute).